# VS2022 demands "Configure your workspace mappings" even though my workspace was mapped and I have changes to check in

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a lot of changes to check in for one of my projects, but Visual Studio 2022 gives me a "Configure your workspace mappings to get started developing." message.

I tried re-connecting to my project through Team Explorer and using Manage Connections, but I still get the message. I hate the thought that I have to remap everything down again only to replace it with my changes from another folder.

I am using the old TFS source system as I have not yet migrated to a Git Repository.

Can anyone suggest an edit to a config file for VS or something so I can get past the problem?

Comment: Are you using old-school TFS - or Git-in-TFS?

Comment: I am using old TFS, as I haven't migrated to Git repository yet.

Comment: I checked out the Related questions, and I think I found an answer. Can we close this question?

Comment: If you think you've found an answer then you should post it as an answer.